# download text file from url python

Tags: python, flask

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2S65.png)i am using python 2.7 Flask for developing web app. i am trying to download a text file from specific URL and save in static folder in application  .here is my code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

uurl = 'http://textfiles.com/100/ad.txt'


def download(t_url):
    response = urlopen(t_url)
    data = response.read()
    txt_str = str(data)
    lines = txt_str.split("\\n")
    des_url = 'static/forcast.txt'
    fx = open(des_url,"w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line+ "\n")
    fx.close()

download(uurl)
```

now i run this and get following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/ff.py", line 17, in <module>
    download(uurl)
  File "/Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/ff.py", line 12, in download
    fx = open(des_url,"w")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/forcast.txt'
```

Comment: this works. use `os.getcwd()` to find out which directory it is writing this file to.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your code as it downloads the file in the same directory of your python script. so specify the location of the folder.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

uurl = 'http://textfiles.com/100/ad.txt'

def download(t_url):
    response = urlopen(t_url)
    data = response.read()
    txt_str = str(data)
    lines = txt_str.split("\\n")
    des_url = 'folder/forcast.csv'
    fx = open(des_url,"w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line+ "\n")
    fx.close()

download(uurl)
```

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/ff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/ff.py", line 17, in <module>
    download(uurl)
  File "/Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/ff.py", line 12, in download
    fx = open(des_url,"w")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/forcast.txt'

Comment: did you create the folder? you have to create the folder first.

Comment: you created `/Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/static` ?

Comment: @sanamasghar Stael has the right idea of having `os.getcwd() + '/static/forcast.txt'` that should place it in `/Users/sanam/PycharmProjects/ff/static`

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Applications/PyCharm 2.app/Contents/bin/static/forcast.txt'

Comment: how i correct this path to Users/sanam/pycharmProjects/ff/static

Comment: Oh that's your problem, you were executing the python script in pycharm

Comment: you need to change `des_url` to be the correct path. I don't know how your files are structured, but use the whole path for example `r'C:/Users/sanam/pycharmProjects/ff/static/forcast.txt'`

Comment: except obviously from the direction of your `/` you are using unix so not `C:` but hopefully you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

uurl = 'http://textfiles.com/100/ad.txt'

def download(t_url):
    response = urlopen(t_url)
    data = response.read()
    txt_str = str(data)
    lines = txt_str.split("\\n")
    des_url = 'folder/add.txt'
    with open(des_url,"w"):
        for line in lines:
            fx.write(line+ "\n")


download(uurl)
```